# Invalid unique validation with additive user_id field

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 6 I have table sda_user_props :

```
id  int(10) unsigned Auto Increment 
user_id int(10) unsigned    
name    varchar(50) 
value   varchar(255)    
created_at  timestamp [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP]
```

where name is unique for any user_id and in request I add user to Model Method, which returns 
rules app/Http/Requests/UserPropRequest.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\UserProp;

class UserPropRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $request= Request();
        $loggedUser      = Auth::guard('api')->user();
        return UserProp::getUserPropValidationRulesArray( ($loggedUser->id ?? null), $request->get('id'), ['user_id'] );
    }
}
```

and in model I have defined :

```
    public static function getUserPropValidationRulesArray( $user_id, $user_prop_id = null, array $skipFieldsArray= []) : array
    {

        $validationRulesArray = [
            'user_id'    => 'required|exists:'.( with(new User)->getTable() ).',id',
            'name'       => 'required|max:50|unique:'.( with(new UserProp)->getTable() ).',user_id,'.$user_id.'|unique:user_props,name,'.$user_prop_id,
            'value'        => 'required|max:255',
        ];

        foreach( $skipFieldsArray as $next_field ) {
            if(!empty($validationRulesArray[$next_field])) {
                unset($validationRulesArray[$next_field]);
            }
        }
        return $validationRulesArray;
    }
```

and my validation does not work properly and tracing sql I see :

```
   SELECT count(*)     AS aggregate 
    FROM `sda_user_props` 
    WHERE `user_id` = 'name1'     AND `id` <> '1'
```

If I entered 'name1' value.

Looks like rule 'name' is invalid, but which valid ?

**MODIFIED :**
That is does not work
With rules defined as :

```
$userTable = with(new User)->getTable();
$userPropTable = with(new UserProp)->getTable();
$validationRulesArray = [
    'user_id' => ['required', "exists:{$userTable},id"],
    'name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
    'value' => ['required', 'max:255'],
];

$validationRulesArray['name'][] =
    Rule::unique($userPropTable)->ignore($user_id, 'user_id')
       ->where(function ($query) use ($user_prop_id) {
           return $query->where('name', $user_prop_id);
       });
```

I log rules array:

```
array (
  'user_id' => 
  array (
    0 => 'required',
    1 => 'exists:users,id',
  ),
  'name' => 
  array (
    0 => 'required',
    1 => 'max:50',
    2 => 
    Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique::__set_state(array(
       'ignore' => 1,
       'idColumn' => 'user_id',
       'table' => 'user_props',
       'column' => 'NULL',
       'wheres' => 
      array (
      ),
       'using' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        Closure::__set_state(array(
        )),
      ),
    )),
  ),
  'value' => 
  array (
    0 => 'required',
    1 => 'max:255',
  ),
)
```

And I see invalid sql :

```
   SELECT count(*)     AS aggregate 
    FROM `sda_user_props` 
    WHERE `name` = 'A'     AND `user_id` <> '1'     AND (`name` is null)
```

I suppose must be condition

```
`user_id` == '1'  // not <>
```

and what is this condition :

```
AND (`name` is null)
```

'A' - is entered text and user_id==1

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the combination of `name user_id` to be unique together? Because I see you have two rules for unique on the name property.

Comment: No must be 1 rule : uniqeu for a pair of fields : user_id=>name. Which is valid syntax ?

Comment: You have me confused there. It sounds like your saying what I'm saying, but differently. You want the name to be unique together with the user_id, not both of them to be unique on their own?

Comment: Yes, the  table has UNIQUE Index on fields user_id, name

Answer (score 1):

First make your rules into array, so its easier to work with them. Then use a Rule class method to define the uniqueness with a where clause:

```
$userTable = with(new User)->getTable();
$userPropTable = with(new UserProp)->getTable();
$validationRulesArray = [
    'user_id' => ['required', "exists:{$userTable},id"],
    'name' => ['required', 'max:50'],
    'value' => ['required', 'max:255'],
];

$validationRulesArray['name'][] = Rule::unique($userPropTable)->ignore($user_id, 'user_id')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($user_prop_id) {
        return $query->where('name', $user_prop_id);
});
```

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED block